# Can't compile Truffle project that imports a .sol with different pragma version

Tags: truffle, solc, compiler, import

I have a contract `pragma solidity 0.6.12` version that imports several `0.6.12` version contracts and one `pragma solidity 0.8.0`.

My `truffle-config`:

```
compilers: {
    solc: {
       version: "^0.6.12 <=0.8.0",
        },
      },
```

This configuration throws an error when compiling:

```
Error: Truffle is currently using solc ^0.6.12 <=0.8.0, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity ^0.7.0"
```

How can I correctly import multiple contracts with multiple versions imports ?

Comment: Did you try replacing this `^0.6.12 <=0.8.0` with `0.7.0`?

Comment: @Icarus23 Yes and it throws "Truffle is currently using solc ^0.7.0, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity ^0.6.0".

Comment: As far as I've seen from your replies, it means that you have to go through your contracts(it usually shows what contract it is in the terminal after you compile your project) and manually replace  the version of that specific contract with the version you're using(which is 0.7.0). Apparently you are using different truffle solc versions for multiple contracts.

Answer (score 0):

Go in your `truffle-config.js` and modify the lines with the `version` version

```
...
 // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.6.12",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
    }
  },
...
```

Comment: Already tried, it doesn't work. Throws the same error with different versions

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
compilers: {
  solc: {
    version: "pragma",
  },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For your contract, have you used ^0.6.12? That should allow you to interact with any other versions above the one you intend to use.

Comment: I've already tried this but it will throw the same error with according versions